# jquery using fadeToggle for multiple for multiple buttons and hidden text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble getting fadeToggle to work.  I'm using it to reveal text upon clicking a another div.  This is intended to be used for multiple elements, so I'm hoping there can be an elegant and efficient way to handle all of them.

Here's what I current have - which doesn't work (I don't think I'm using "this" correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#daily').click(function () {
    $('this p').fadeToggle(100);
  }):
  $('#color').click(function () {
    $('this p').fadeToggle(100);
  }):
  $('#bw').click(function () {
    $('this p').fadeToggle(100);
  }):
}):
```

Here's the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qEKJe/

I'd like to use this in combination with a .load() call, don't know if that will change things.

Also - bonus points if you can make it so revealing a new text block closes any that are currently showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your selector an instead the `id` for each one use the classname. Also the declaration `$('this p')` is invalid you need this:

```
$('.selectopt').click(function () {
    $(this).next('p').fadeToggle();
})
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEKJe/1/)**

Comment: Cool this works.  I didn't know about .next() - that's very effective.  Any idea how to update this script such that Toggling a new 'p' would close any currently open one?

Comment: @user3180105 yep don't use fadetoggle then just first fadeout all and then fadein the relative to the element like this http://jsfiddle.net/qEKJe/5/

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I need.  You sir get a check

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qEKJe/4/

Added classes to your p's.

```
<div class="select">
    <div>
        <div id="daily" class="selectopt">Daily</div>
        <p class="daily-p">Daily photos description</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="color" class="selectopt">Color</div>
        <p class="color-p">Color photos description</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="bw"  class="selectopt">Black & White</div>
        <p class="bw-p">Black & White photos description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work for all of them now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectopt').click(function () {
        var x = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.' + x + '-p').fadeToggle(100);
    });
});
```